# Добавление обработчика для нажатия клавиш

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Моя задача заключается в том, чтобы сделать собственный рандом. Я в процессе создания случайных чисел определенной длины, например 3 знака. Генерация должна происходить по средствам кликов мыши и нажатий клавиш. PictureBox служит областью в которой пользователь может кликать мышкой, которые я ловлю беру из них координаты и складываю, вычитаю и т.д. Теперь мне надо сделать определение клавиш, чтобы получать их коды и проводить математические преобразования этих кодов, например складывать.

Я не знаю почему мой обработчик не цепляется и как его правильно зацепить. Сами обработчики будут запускаться по нажатию на кнопку, а по нажатию на другую отключаться, по крайней мере я на это надеюсь.

По нажатию на кнопку вызывается следующий код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.MouseClick += OnPictureBoxClicked;

    pictureBox1.PreviewKeyDown += OnPreviewKeyDown;
}


void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //e.KeyData.ToString();
}
```

Собственно пытаюсь добавиться добавить обработчик по аналогии с кликом, но лезут ошибки. Хотя обработчик клика работает. Не пойму что я делаю не так.

Ошибка возникает, например, такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, сейчас я каждый раз подписываюсь на обработчики, как мне избежать этого? Было бы полезно знать.

Comment: `но лезут ошибки` предлагаете догадаться, что за ошибки?

Comment: Вы на `button1_Click` подписываетесь на события. Если 100 раз нажать и 100 раз вызвать `button1_Click`, то вы 100 раз подпишетесь.

Comment: Я если честно даже не уверен, что то что я хочу написать должно быть написано именно так, через эти события и обработчики...

Comment: поясните вашу задачу. Сейчас это бессмыслица какая то, какие то коды, зачем то их складывать, причем тут picturebox вообще и как код, что вы показали вообще к задаче относится - все это непонятно.

Comment: Вы лучше сразу подпишитесь на все события, которые нужно, а как реагировать на эти события - уже решайте по состоянию объектов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй при загрузке формы или при инициализации подписываться. Тип так

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  pictureBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(OnKeyDown);
  
  // можно и так pictureBox1.KeyDown += OnKeyDown; 
}

void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  // TODO
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Как мне подписывать правильно?